# How to get android device id?

Tags: java, android, testing, automation, appium

How to get android device id? I don't know whats the "context".

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.provider.Settings;

public class getDeviceID {

    public void getAndroidID(Context context) {
        String android_id= Settings.System.getString(context.getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);

        System.out.println(android_id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a unique Android device ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id)

Comment: Context is the instance of the current class in which you will call this method.

Comment: @DeepakRana No it isn't.  Its the Activity, Service, or Application which is running.  Not the class.  If that's all it was, you'd use this.

Comment: if you are fresher then please study basics from tutorial web sites or android's developer site. and please search question before posting.

Answer (score 3):

Create context for you application like this

```
private Context context = this;
```

Put this lines inside onCreate

```
    String android_id = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(),
            Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);

    Toast.makeText(context, "android_id= " + android_id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

And to know more about `context` refer [this link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html)